# Joda Time - different between timezones

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I want to convert the current time to the time in a specific timezone with Joda time.

Is there a way to convert `DateTime time = new DateTime()` to a specific timezone, or perhaps to get the number of hours difference between `time.getZone()` and another `DateTimeZone` to then do `time.minusHours` or `time.plusHours`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I want to convert the current time to the time in a specific timezone with Joda time.

It's not really clear whether you've already *got* the current time or not. If you've already got it, you can use [`withZone`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-):

```
DateTime zoned = original.withZone(zone);
```

If you're just fetching the current time, use the [appropriate constructor](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-):

```
DateTime zoned = new DateTime(zone);
```

or use [`DateTime.now`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#now-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-):

```
DateTime zoned = DateTime.now(zone);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I already have the current time - sorry for not being too clear about that. original.withZone does the trick.

Comment: Could you also do `DateTime.now(zone)`?

Comment: @JoshPinter: Yes, that would be fine too - I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 10):

Check out [DateTimeZone](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) & [Interval](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    // translate to London local time
    DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
```

Interval:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end); //start and end are two DateTimes
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZonedDateTime.now() is same as ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()). In
        // order to specify a specific timezone, use ZoneId.of(...) e.g.
        // ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtDefaultTz = ZonedDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(zdtDefaultTz);

        // Convert zdtDefaultTz to a ZonedDateTime in another timezone e.g.
        // to ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdtDefaultTz.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-07-25T15:48:10.584414+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-07-25T10:48:10.584414-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/x6VJaV)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>